# React native dimensions for Google Pixel XL and 2 XL

Tags: react-native, height, width, dimensions, google-pixel

I'm having trouble rendering a lottie animation in Google Pixel XL and 2 XL.  But I don't have that device on hand, does anyone know the width and height in react native unit? or how do you do to detect this devices?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You can use [`Dimensions`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) from React Native for width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement by importing *Dimensions* from react-native package itself as below

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const window = Dimensions.get('window');
const screenHeight = window.height;
const screenWidth = window.width;
```

And use it appropriately inside any element

```
<View style={{height: screenHeight - 80}}>
```